# How can i get City and State name from PlaceAutocomplete api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have done the piece of code to get city name. But now as per new requriement i also need state name from the com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete api.
You can refer the piece of code what i have done for getting city.

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                    .setCountry("IN")
                    .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS)
                    .build();

            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)//MODE_OVERLAY
                    .setFilter(autocompleteFilter)
                    .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Utils.dismissProgressBar();
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                AppLog.log(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
                AppLog.log(TAG, "getAddress: " + place.getAddress());
                mCityName.setText(place.getName());
            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                AppLog.log(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
                Toast.makeText(status.getStatusMessage(), true);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Toast.makeText("Unable to find place", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me this way:

```
final Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this,data);
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
try
{
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude, 1);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
    String country = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();  

} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is unreliable. The geocoder will throw an exception in lot of cases where your users will need to restart their device for this to work properly. We used this in our product and had to remove it later on. Refer to this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009

Answer (score 0):

Using `Geocoder` We can get City name.
Try this.

```
final Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this,data);
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
try
{
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude, 1);
    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
    //String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);  

} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i am not getting state as a single string. also i am getting city null